# trying to display a 0 in the terny operator in Java with conditional statements

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Hi I am trying to display the 0 when time.get(calendar.MINUITE)  1 - 9

the time for min reads 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 then 10 11 12 13

the time diplays fine when going 10 and up

but I have a conditional statement saying when the time is less the 10, display a 0 in front of the current number. I understand system.out.format, but I can not add this to a terny operator

this is my java

```
   Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();

    int min = 1;//time.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int hour =  time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int blank = Integer.parseInt("0");

    int hourOfDay = ((hour > 12) ? (hour - 12) : hour);
    int zero = ((min > 9 ) ? min : blank+min);        
    System.out.println("The time is " + hourOfDay + ":" + zero );
```

so lets say the time  is 6:1 how will I make it display the 0 in front of the one, but then when 10 - 59 appears for min, the 0 wont be in front of the number like 6:030. Unless there is a conditional format system.out I can add in when there is less than 10

Comment: This is not related at all with the ternary operator but with formatting numbers. There are lots of questions about this already in SO, search for them.

Comment: Change blank and zero to String-Type. Otherwise blank+min just adds 0 to min. Or use `String.format("%d02", min)` to add the 0 to your minute.

Comment: ok I add the 0 to the min. I know how to do that, but when it goes above 10, the 0 is going to stay, get what I am saying?

Comment: Reread @TheConstructor's comment. `String.format` does exactly what you want.

Comment: `ternary` operator. Unary means one, binary means two, ternary means three (three operands, that is -- the conditional, the value if the conditional is true, and the value if it is false).

Comment: @Pshemo good catch. Even the user-name is the same O.o

Comment: @TheConstructor Yes, what a coincidence :)

Comment: Again this is because your are using the interger 0 rather than the character "0". You actively parse a perfectly good String to an integer. Why do you do that?

Answer (score 1):

Your code will never produce a leading zero in your output as 0+1=1, 0+2=2, ...

Try one of these:

Ternary Take 1:

```
String zero = ((min > 9 ) ? String.valueOf(min) : "0"+min);
```

Ternary Take 2:

```
System.out.println("The time is " + hourOfDay + ":" + ((min > 9 ) ? "" : "0") + min);
```

String.format:

```
String zero = String.format("%02d", min);
```

System.out.printf:

```
System.out.printf("The time is %d:%02d%n", hourOfDay, zero);
```

I would tend to use one of the later two in this case. Depending on whether or not outputting to System.out is you concern, the third could be the best. Of course there are a lot other options.